# How to remove /home from url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

I have a url: `www.mysite.com` with clean urls via .htaccess, here is the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything is working great other than I would like `www.mysite.com/home` to convert to `www.mysite.com`. Essentially I want to remove the `/home`. I have tried several attempts with examples found online but nothing has worked. Hopefully someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [L,R]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` tells the server to not rewrite if a directory that actually exists is requested.

If you remove that line above from `.htaccess`, then `www.mywebsite.com/home` will lead to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /home [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 # Redirect from http://domain.com/home/... to http://domain.com/...
 RewriteRule ^home\/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^home\/?$ / [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

or else if you mean to have all contents of your site into a subfolder from root try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 # Point from http://domain.com/... to http://domain.com/home/...
 RewriteCond $1 !^home
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^ /home/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```